# How to change a webpart list view to another list view when a custom button is clicked on a wiki page?

Tags: sharepoint, button, click, web-parts

I created a list and setup 3 views using "filters" in Sharepoint 2010.  On the main wiki page, I created a custom dataview that brought the list into a wiki page and the view was the default view.  I have created 3 img buttons and placed them into the datalistview just above the columns in the list so on the wiki page you see the 3 img btns (new, updated, contacts) then the default list view.

What I can't seem to get working (I am not a programmer) is when one of the buttons are clicked, I need the webpart to show the related list view to show on the wiki page, in the webpart.   So if I clicked on "New" button, the "new" list view replaces the default view in the webpart.  hope this makes sense....

I have been searching for days trying various code that references iframes, and even on this site looked at button click change view questions but none have actually addressed this item that I could tell.  Any help would be wonderful!